# How to replace x with a function of x over a range of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I currently have a spreadsheet that has values, which we'll call x. I would like to change each cell over the range of values to be y=ax^2+b, where a and b are constants that I already know. How would I write a function in VBA that runs over all of these values and changes each individually?

If there is another way that you believe I should do this (python, matlab, etc), please let me know as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you not use normal replace?

Comment: All the values are different, so I'm not really sure how to do that? Since you have to Find what value to replace, and I think I need to define each cell as a variable

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function it's a procedure  If you want to change the values then:

```
Sub ChangeValues 
Dim r as range
dim a as double
dim b as double
a = 2  'whatever value
b = 3  'whatever
For each r in Range("your range here")
r = r.value^2 x a + b
next r
End Sub
```

If you want to preserve the original values then the centre line becomes

```
 r.formula = "=" & a & "x" & r.value & "^2 + " & b
```

Comment: This procedure makes sense, but it is saying that there is a syntax error with the line 
"r = r.value^2 x a + b"

Comment: `r = r.value^2 * a + b`